# What is a best way to have nested project in Angular

Tags: angular, angular9

What will be the best approach to split my website two separate ways without needing to generate two different angular project?.

1. Website Application
2. Admin Area/CMS page

For example [www.mywebsiteurl.com](http://www.mywebsiteurl.com) is official website while [www.mywebsiteurl.com/admin](http://www.mywebsiteurl.com/admin) for managing web content.

**Currently I have this**

[image: App routing page]
[image: Work flow]

I don't want the header, menu and footers component to appear on any admin pages, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the header, menu and footer in every route that is not admin, and don't include them in the admin route.

It is as simple as that :)

EDIT: As the suggested fix would be too long to implement, you could, in your main component, subscribe to the `ActiveRoute`. Upon route, you could assign true or false to a boolean, let's say `admin`.

Then with a `ng-if` remove elements that are not needed when this variable is false or true.

Comment: thank you for answering...But that way is very hard. considering that you have 50 pages you have to be adding them manually of all pages. Can I bind with header, menu and footer dynamically from admin page? i.e once the route is pointing to /admin page.  header, menu and footer component should be deactivated or disabled. @mikegross

Comment: Then is your main component, track the `activeroute` by subscribing to it and upon it assign a variable with an ngif in your dom to make the header, menu and footer disappear. It's a bit hacky but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

@mikegross from your guardians here's how I resolved it. Many thanks

```js
disableComponent = false;

  constructor(location: Location, router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      if(location.path() != '/admin'){
        this.disableComponent = true;
      }else{
        this.disableComponent=false;
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
<app-header *ngIf='disableComponent'></app-header>
<app-site-menu *ngIf='disableComponent'></app-site-menu>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-footer *ngIf='disableComponent'></app-footer>
```